# If $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n$ exists is it true that $a_n$ is bounded?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

There is a theorem in limits that says that if $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n$ exists then the sequence a_n is bounded.

And my professor gave me an example for this. Consider $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$. The maximum bounds for this sequence is $1$ and the minimum bound is $0$.

Now instead if I take $a_n=\frac{1}{n-1}$ then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ which means the limit exists. Now though the sequence has a minimum bound of $0$ it has no maximum bound.

Now is there some sort of caveat in the theorem I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure that it has no maximum bound? $n$ is an integer.

Comment: when $n=1 \ , \frac{1}{n-1}=\infty$

Comment: Hello :) Why not? $\frac{1}{n-1}\leq 1$ for all integers $n\geq 2$. For $n=1$ it is not even well-defined.

Comment: The sequence is not defined when $n=1$. Do not mistake $1/0$ as $\infty$.

Comment: The sequence $a_n=\frac{1}{n-1}$ is defined for $n \ge 2,$ hence $a_2=1$ is the maximum.

Comment: If $(a_n)$ is real sequence which converges then it is bounded. You cannot divide by $0$ so your sequence is not even defined.

Comment: So $\frac{1}{n-M}$ is not a valid well defined sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a sequence is defined as a (real-valued) function on the naturals.
$$a:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$$
If you try to define a sequence by $a_n=\frac{1}{n-1}$, then you run into problems when you find that $a_1=\frac{1}{0}\notin\mathbb{R}$, meaning that this is not a valid sequence. Now, we could modify the definition above to allow sequences that start with $a_2$ to fix this, but that doesn't tell us what the real problem is here. The key thing to note is that each element of the sequence is a real number, which must be finite, which also tells us that any finite subset of the sequence must be bounded. The only way the sequence can be unbounded is if there is an infinite subsequence that goes to $\pm\infty$, which implies that the sequence does not converge.

Comment: So you are telling me that any sequence should have an infinite subsequence that goes to $\pm \infty$ for it to be described as unbounded? by which this implies any subsequence of the form $\frac{1}{n-M}$ is not really unbounded?

Comment: @Orpheus Yes, a sequence is unbounded if $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^+\exists n\in\mathbb{N}\text{ s.t. }\lvert a_n\rvert>x$.

Comment: but by the definition of an unbounded sequence given by ya.....$a_n=\frac{1}{n-M}$ is unbounded since there always exists an $a_M$ s.t $a_M \gt \forall x \in R^{+}$

Comment: For such $a_n$, $a_M$ is not well defined. For all other terms, they are upper and lower bounded by $1$ and $-1$, respectively. @Orpheus

Comment: @Orpheus $\frac{1}{M-M}$ is not a real number, so that sequence cannot be defined for $n=M$.

Comment: so $\frac{1}{n-M}$ is not a valid sequence

Comment: @Orpheus Not necessarily, if $M$ is not an integer or $n$ starts at a value greater than $M$, then it is valid.

Comment: I saw another sort of a theorem or fact, that removing elements from a sequence does not change the limit of the sequence as n $\to \infty$. So as per what your saying...i simply need to define my sequence...and not consider elements with $n \le M$ for $\frac{1}{n-M}$ it to be a valid sequence with proper bounds and for the finite limit to hold...

Comment: @Orpheus Yes, that's correct, although it is sufficient to only remove the element with $n=M$.